# Click change color in jQuery 3.6.0

Tags: jquery

I want to click changing background color in jQuery 3.6.0. I mix jQuery + classic JavaScript, because I think rgb is crazy for me in jQuery.

I have a button:

```
<button id="bgcolor">Click Change Color</button>
```

jQuery example 1:

```js
$("#bgcolor").click(() => {
  if (document.getElementById("bgcolor").style.backgroundColor != "Green")
    document.getElementById("bgcolor").style.backgroundColor = "Green"
  else document.getElementById("bgcolor").style.backgroundColor = "Blue"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script><button id="bgcolor">Click Change Color</button>
```

jQuery example 2:

```js
$("#bgcolor").on("click", () => {
  if (document.getElementById("bgcolor").style.backgroundColor != "Green")
    document.getElementById("bgcolor").style.backgroundColor = "Green"
  else document.getElementById("bgcolor").style.backgroundColor = "Blue"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<button id="bgcolor">Click Change Color</button>
```

Both two codes work, but only change the button's color to green. Why doesn't it execute changing the button color to blue if I click the button twice?

Comment: **Always** debug what you're actually getting - what does `console.log(document.getElementById("bgcolor").style.backgroundColor)` give you (F12 in the browser console tab).   It's probably giving you "green" and `"Green" != "green"`

Answer (score 1):

It's actually `green` and `blue`, instead of `Blue`

(And I don't know about `Green` and I don't even know how it worked for you..., but still i just changed it into `green`)

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("bgcolor")

$("#bgcolor").on("click", () => {
  if (elem.style.backgroundColor != "green")
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "green"
  else
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<button id="bgcolor">Click Change Color</button>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m no, i mean the syntax, i didn't know that `Green` still gives you the same value as `green`

Comment: `elem.style.backgroundColor = "Green"` gets converted to `green`